# iOS JSON Parsing Objective-C and pass POST method parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I want to parsing JSON in android using volleylibrary for login.In Login activity,send two parameters(username,password) via post and response like below.

parameters : username,password

```
for success:

{
"status": 1,
"message": "successfully login" ,  
    "result": [
{
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "Img": "http://img.com/img.png"
}      
       ]
}
```

for Error:

```
{
"status": 0,
"message": "email or password doesn’t exist"    
}
```

Comment: android me krna hai ya iOS me? (You want to do it in iOS or Android?)

Comment: can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

API call Using AFNetworking with POST method in iOS

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[parameters setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
```

Then Call method

```
- (void)apiRequestForPOSTWithServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName andParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameter withCompletion:(void(^)(id response, BOOL isSuccess))completion
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, serviceName];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    completion(responseObject,YES);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    completion(error,NO);
}];
}
```

Need to parse the response object after getting the data from server

```
- (void)parseDataWithDict:(id) responeDict
{
NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *) responeDict;
NSString *status = dict[@“status”];
NSString *message = dict[@“message”];
NSDictionary *dictRes = [responeDict[@"result"] firstObject];  // If the result having more data in array, need to iterate the array
NSString *name = dictRes[@“name”];
NSString *email = dictRes[@“email”];
NSString *Img = dictRes[@“Img”];
// If you have any model object class, then add to it and return the object
}
```

Thanks...happy coding.